# SheetJS: Do Not Include Headers In json_to_sheet

Tags: js-xlsx, xlsx-js, sheetjs

The [SheetJS documentation](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#array-of-objects-input) shows a way to take a JSON Object and convert it to an Excel sheet. From their example:

```js
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([
  {S:1,h:2,e:3,e_1:4,t:5,J:6,S_1:7},
  {S:2,h:3,e:4,e_1:5,t:6,J:7,S_1:8}
], {header:["S","h","e","e_1","t","J","S_1"]});
```

By default, the header information is Object.keys.

The output looks like this in excel:

[image: excel output]

My question: how do I leave out the header when converting from Json_to_sheet? I do not want the header in my output, only the numbers in the order of Object.keys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please find the updated answer below:

```
if(typeof XLSX == 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([
  {S:1,h:2,e:3,e_1:4,t:5,J:6,S_1:7},
  {S:2,h:3,e:4,e_1:5,t:6,J:7,S_1:8}
], {skipHeader: 1});

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "No Header");

var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', type:'array'});
saveAs(new Blob([wbout],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), "test.xlsx");
```

Here we can use **skipHeader** option inorder to skip the JSON Key values to default as a column name.

Comment: @toby ,Thanks for your suggestion. I am newbie in answering question and will definitely keep this in mind for next answers.

Comment: should be `skipHeader: true` :) (https://sheetjs.gitbooks.io/docs/#array-of-objects-input)